# SOAP Header Authentication for every method call in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

Basically every method call to my SOAP web service required user authentication.
So this is what SOAP header should look like:

```
<soap:Header>
  <HTNGHeader xmlns="http://htng.org/1.1/Header/">
    <From>
      <systemId />
      <Credential>
        <userName>string</userName>
        <password>string</password>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <systemId />
    </To>
    <timestamp />
    <echoToken />
      <transactionId />
    <action />
  </HTNGHeader>
</soap:Header>
```

This is what I found so far [link](http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client/).
I'm sure that I have to make change in this block

```
      try {
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();

        SOAPElement security =
                header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

        SOAPElement usernameToken =
                security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
        usernameToken.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:wsu"), "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

        SOAPElement username =
                usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
        username.addTextNode("TestUser");

        SOAPElement password =
                usernameToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");
        password.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
        password.addTextNode("TestPassword");

        //Print out the outbound SOAP message to System.out
        message.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I can't make it right. I would appreciate all your idea.

Thanks

Comment: "But I can't make it right", and what the problem is?

Comment: @vzamanillo if you see the [link](http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client/) what the soap header look like is http://cl.ly/image/0j2Z3g2p3l3m but I need something like this http://cl.ly/image/2P2l3d2e0P2k

Comment: @vzamanillo Basically this [article](http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client/) almost solve my problem. the things is I need quite different header.

Comment: Your header is not a WS-Security standard header, and seems like your endpoint service does not require sec in the standard WS-Security way, so... simply create your desired header and add it to the SOAP message.

Comment: Yes, you're right. it is not standard header. That why I have trouble making it.